# Display HTML page inside mail body with Email-ext plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-attachments, email-ext

I am new to Jenkins and I want to know how it is possible to display the HTML report (not the HTML code) generated after a successful build inside a mail body (not as an attachment).

I want to know the exact steps I should follow and what should be the content of my possible jelly template.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Look deeper into the [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) documentations. No need for groovy here.

Just make sure Content Type is set to HTML and add the following to the body:

```
${FILE,path="my.html"}
```

This will place the `my.html` content in your email body (location of file is relative to job's workspace. I use it and it works well.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: Note that you must have the Jenkins version **1.532.1** (or higher) to support this feature with the email-ext plugin.

Comment: i set the content to html and did as mentioned now it is returning an error saying in the body of the mail saying `ERROR: File '/data/test.html' does not exist`

Comment: `/data/test.html` is an absolute path from the root of the file system (leading slash). Try only `data/test.html`.

Comment: supposed that the absolute path of my html file is `/data/jenkins/jobs/GAMETV/htmlreports/HTML_Report/GAMETV.html` what should i put as path ?

Comment: As an initial test, put the whole path `/data/jenkins/jobs/GAMETV/htmlreports/HTML_Report/GAMETV.html` to see if it works.

Comment: Is your Jenkins running as a slave? Is the file accessible to the user running Jenkins? Is the java process that runs the Jenkins instance located on the same file system as the file? Try putting the file in the job's workspace and try just that.

Comment: the html file i am trying to show is actually the html file generated on my last build so it should be accessible to the user as it is generated by the Jenkins' job

Comment: Try testing with a manually created file in the workspace. Make sure you have an updated version of the plugin...

Comment: it seems that the problem is with my Jenkins version as the one i have is ver. `1.513` and the required one for the plugin is `1.532.1`

Comment: Well, did you manage? Did you update your Jenkins and plugin? If so, let me know so I can edit my answer for others to benefit.

Comment: yes i managed to do it.just mention that the email-ext plugin needs at least 1.532.1 version of jenkins

Comment: I was able to use this functionality with Jenkins ver. 1.509.4 and Email-ext 2.35.1. Also You can use absolute path and environment variables :)

Comment: this syntax sends html report in the email but i am looking for link to send in email. can some one help me on this?

Comment: Can i somehow enlarge the content of file in email. It looks small

Comment: @EldadAK your solution didn't work for me. For Editable Email notification Content Type selected as Html and Default Content field I've given value per your answer.  Please clarify what step am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you add the `${FILE,path="my.html"}` to the email body? Do you have any error?

Comment: @EldadAK I did below steps but couldn't get it working. ${FILE,path="workspace/target/site/serenity/index.html"} in Content field of Editable Email Notification > Triggers > Always. It shows error message "ERROR: File 'workspace/target/site/serenity/index.html' does not exist". Can you please share screen shot

Comment: Got it working by updating "Editable Email Notification" > "Content Type" value to HTML (text/html) and "Default Content" field value to "${FILE,path="target/site/serenity/index.html"}. Didn't do any changes for Triggers fields.

Comment: I am also working on the same and able to see the report in mail body but the content display is not proper so do I need to any CSS in configuration property to get the proper display in email body?

Comment: Unfortunately this fails when job is aborted. It throws Null Pointer exception.

Comment: Assuming you have expressions in the html like '${BUILD_NUMBER}' will they get resolved  or will the remain as are. I need a way to format them before the actual send.

Answer (score 11):

Besides reading the file with `body: ${FILE,path="index.html"}`, you need to set the proper content type, either globally or explicitly for one execution, with `mimeType: 'text/html`.

```
emailext subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
                    body: '${FILE,path="index.html"}',
                    recipientProviders: [
                        [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
                        [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
                        [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']
                    ], 
                    replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
                    to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS',
                    mimeType: 'text/html'
```

Comment: I received the email but css is not displayed. I am using dashboard.html of extent report

Comment: Yes. My problem is caused by missing the  mimeType. Great.

Answer (score 8):

It worked for me with Jenkins 1.558

```
${FILE,path="target/failsafe-reports/emailable-report.html"}
```

Comment: can you please add screen shot showing where to add this value ?

Answer (score 4):

#### If you use a custom path

I had a complication trying to achieve this result because my path was dynamically changing and I had to use a variable inside a `FILE` variable. So when I tried any of the following

```
body: '${FILE,path=${report}}'
body: "${FILE,path=${report}}"
body: '''${FILE,path=${report}}'''
```

and many more, it didn't work. On the other hand I couldn't read the file with groovy because of Jenkins restrictions

**My workaround** was to read the html directly with shell like so

```
html_body = sh(script: "cat ${report}", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

and then just send the email

```
emailext replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
  subject: "subject",
  to: EMAIL,
  mimeType: 'text/html',
  body: html_body
```

where `${report}` was a path to html file like `/var/jenkins/workspace_318/report.html`

Answer (score 3):

**It should be something like this**:

[image]

**Navigation**:

```
Configure -> Editable Email Notification
```

**Default Content**:

```
${FILE,path="path/result.html"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to assign the link to the environment variable and then you can use that variable to print in the email using ${ENV, var=ENV_VARIABLE}.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Editable Email Notification](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) post build action to send html content as part of mail body.

Copy html content in **`Default Content`** and select   **`Content Type`** as **`HTML (text/html)`**, as in below image:
[image]

Comment: As of 2021, it seems to have been deprecated.

Comment: @EladAvron if you face issue that instead of HTML content it puts the actual file path in the email body, then check if this latest version of the plugin - https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro/ is installed. I faced this issue and resolved when I updated this plugin. (it is internally used by Email Ext plugin, but seems to be not auto updated along with Email Ext update)