# MSBuild email alert to list failed tests

Tags: msbuild, mstest

I'm using TFS, MSBuild and MSTest for automated build and test solution. When some unit tests fail; build partially succeeds and I get email just giving the error information.

Is there any way that I can customize the e-mail content? I want the failed test names and fail reason listed in the mail. Even the test result file as an attachment(1 MB) would do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a Jenkins plugin called "Email-ext plugin" [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) maybe that could help you. However, (I assume) you might need some kind of your own custom template to do what you want.

[Example](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-email)

You can attach a HTML page to your email, likewise you can customize as you want:

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066936/display-html-page-inside-mail-body-with-email-ext-plugin-in-jenkins)