# Custom email through Jenkins CI upon completion of a testng suite

Tags: selenium, jenkins, email

I'm using selenium webdriver(firefox) with java for a test suite in testng. This suite has 10+ test classes, and all of these relay certain messages(for relaying an error message without failing the test) to the final page reached by the suite before closing the browser. In this page, I have all the required error messages concatenated into 1 string(to send in the email body). My question is how to send this to jenkins so i can send out the email.

I'm assuming in jenkins, it'll be the editable email notification under configure, and the recipients and subject, etc can all be hardcoded. I need a way to convey my message from my webdriver code to the email body. Is there a plugin or something else I can use to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: How about writing it to a file and then use the Email Ext plugin as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066936/display-html-page-inside-mail-body-with-email-ext-plugin-in-jenkins)?