# unable to send email with attachment after builing in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I am successfully able to build the job and when i ran the project from jenkins(build) then it creates a workspace say "C:\Users\user.jenkins\workspace\javaproj"

I am using email-ext plugin.
Then if i have any attachment(say abc.txt) at the above location, like temp.txt etcc... and in my jenkings email-notification section, if i specify that file name like abc.txt, Jenkins able to send mail with attachment.

But for ex. if my attachment is in different location than workspace location C:\Users\user.jenkins\workspace\javaproj\a\b\c\abc.txt, 
**then what i need to specify in email configuration section?**

I tried below:

```
complete absolute path: C:\Users\user\.jenkins\workspace\javaproj\a\b\c\abc.txt  -only mail with content is sending not attachment

\a\b\c\abc.txt - some error message ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 

../a/b/c/abc.txt - only mail with content is sending not attachment
```

Comment: Have you tried the <the rest>\javaproj\**\abc.txt pattern ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066936/display-html-page-inside-mail-body-with-email-ext-plugin-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by specifying below:

```
a/b/c/abc.txt
```