# Embed html report in email body using Email-ext plugin on Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

How can I make the email body as the selenium html report. I have followed the methods give in the question [Display HTML page inside mail body with Email-ext plugin in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066936/display-html-page-inside-mail-body-with-email-ext-plugin-in-jenkins), but I'm getting error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
startup failed: WorkflowScript: 6: unexpected token: FILE @ line 6,
column 17.
        body: ${FILE,path="enteryPath/template.html"},
                ^
1 error
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(
ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(
ErrorCollector.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(
ErrorCollector.java:120) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(
ErrorCollector.java:132) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(
AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(
AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(
CompilationUnit.java:168)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(
CompilationUnit.java:943)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(
CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(
CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(
CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)     
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)  
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(
CpsGroovyShell.java:129)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(
CpsGroovyShell.java:123)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(
CpsFlowExecution.java:517)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(
CpsFlowExecution.java:480)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(
WorkflowRun.java:269)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421) Finished: FAILURE
```

The code I used is:

```
node {
    stage ('email')
    {
        emailext (
        subject: "some subject",
        body: ${FILE,path="enteryPath/template.html"},
        to: "email@example.com"
        )  

    }
}
```

Jenkins Version 2.85 
Email extension plugin version 2.60
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed the issue on pipeline by the following code

```
emailext mimeType: 'text/html',
        body: '${FILE,path="Seleniun/test-output/emailable-report.html"}', 
        subject: 'Selenium: Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' Status: currentBuild.result, 
        to: EMAIL_ADD
```

Answer (score 2):

#### If you use a custom path this answer is for you

I had a complication trying to achieve this result because my path was dynamically changing and I had to use a variable inside a `FILE` variable. So when I tried any of the following

```
body: '${FILE,path=${report}}'
body: "${FILE,path=${report}}"
body: '''${FILE,path=${report}}'''
```

and many more, it didn't work. On the other hand I couldn't read the file with groovy because of Jenkins restrictions

**My workaround** was to read the html directly with shell like so

```
html_body = sh(script: "cat ${report}", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

and then just send the email

```
emailext replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
  subject: "subject",
  to: EMAIL,
  mimeType: 'text/html',
  body: html_body
```

where `${report}` was a path to html file like `/var/jenkins/workspace_318/report.html`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use dynamic path or evaluated variable path, you can do the following:

```
 " \ ${FILE,path= \ "${FILE_LOCATION} \ "}"
```

Please note for the back slash, spaces need to be trimmed.